# Stacking words above an equal sign

Tags: equations, formatting

I am writing some class notes, and I like to remind myself how to justify inequalities etc by putting a word above an `=`, `\le` sign etc.

But often, the words intrude upon the actual equation. How can I ensure this does not happen?

For example the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\newcommand\myeq[1]{\stackrel{\mathclap{\normalfont\mbox{#1}}}{ = }}
\begin{document}
$Z_k \in mF+$ then $E(\sum Z_k) \myeq{linearity} \sum E(Z_k) \le \infty$
\end{document}
```

Unfortunately, it comes out like this, intruding upon the `\sum`:

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to omit the `\mathclap` directive. (The `\mathclap{...}` directive makes TeX believe the argument has zero width. That's what's causing the undesirable typographic collisions.)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclareMathOperator{\E}{E} % expectation operator
\newcommand\myeq[1]{\stackrel{\textnormal{#1}}{=}}

\begin{document}
$\E\bigl(\sum Z_k\bigr) \myeq{linearity} \sum\E(Z_k)$
\end{document}
```

"linearity" is possibly needlessly long; consider abbreviating the string to just "lin.".

Comment: I see thank you - i copied something I found elsewhere and did not know what \mathclap does !

Comment: :-) ............

Answer (score 2):

You can use `\buildrel` macro form plain TeX:

```
\def\myeq#1{\buildrel\rm#1\over=}

$ Z_k \in mF+$ then $E(\sum Z_k) \myeq{linearity} \sum E(Z_k) \le \infty$

\bye
```